Why is prop type with optional field unknown in template?
I am coding with VSCode
using vuejs3, ts
When I define props type with interface, if interface has optional field, IDE says that prop type is unknown in template.
If interface has no optional field, everything is working well
Here is problem case:
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Prop {
    item: {
        a?: string
    }
}

defineProps<Prop>()
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{ item }}</div>
    <!-- (property) item: unknown -->
</template>

<style scoped></style>

So if I access the a field of item =>
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts-plugin(2339)
There is no problem if prop type has no optional field like this:
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Prop {
    item: {
        a: string
    }
}

defineProps<Prop>()
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{ item.a }}</div>
    <!-- (property) item: {
        a: string;
    } -->
</template>

<style scoped></style>

How can I use the optional field of prop type correctly?

Since you observe it in VSC, probably because it's a bug in VSC or its plugin. In case of doubt, always check if it can be reproduced with vue-tsc
